# INTEL XDK API is Not Supported by This version Of App Analyz

Tags: android, intel-xdk

When I Use Intel Debug Preview Connecting to My Samsung S3 Or Samsung tab 3. 
I Always Got this Error

INTEL XDK API is Not Supported by This version Of App Analyzer.

[image: error screenshot]

I am using the latest Version Of Intel XDK Sofware in Windows 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Debug and Profiling is in beta in the current Intel XDK, so it does not support any `intel.xdk` APIs, it only supports `Cordova` APIs. You will have to remove all `intel.xdk.*` API calls and `intelxdk.js` script from your app.

Comment: How can debug live with my device using intel.xdk.* api calls?

Comment: use weinre debug, In the test tab of Intel XDK you will find details